# SqlCeServer: How to Store a Single Char?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I've got a column in my **Microsoft SQL CE 3.5 SP2** database called *Type* that needs to store a single character.

To do this, I have formatted the column as `nchar(1)`, and storing the data works fine.

However, whenever I attempt to fill a `DataTable` using *Visual Studio 2010*, the *Type* column values are stored as *string* values.

This really only causes havoc whenever I try to use one of our company methods to test if a given data row has changed. The value stored in memory (a character) is *never* equal to the value read back from the database (since it is a different data type).

Rather than write a special routine that tests every column to see if it is a `char` data type and cast that, is there a different *SQL* data type that I should be assigning to the table's Column?

The list of available columns appears to be {bigint, binary, bit, datetime, float, image, int, money, nchar, ntext, numeric, nvarchar, real, rowversion, smallint, tinyint, uniqueidentifier, varbinary}.

[image]

**Solved**

To determine if my `In Memory` data had changed from the SQL CE Table, I used the following routine:

```
// Class RowData
// private List<CellData> cellList;

public bool Changed(DataTable table) {
  int index = RowIndex(table);
  if (-1 < index) {
    DataRow row = table.Rows[index];
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(col.ColumnName)) {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var cell in cellList) {
          if (cell.ColumnName == col.ColumnName) {
            object o = row[cell.ColumnName];
            if (col.DataType != typeof(string)) {
              if (!cell.Value.Equals(o)) {
                return true; // this fails on a Char.value 'C' != "C"
              }
            } else if (col.MaxLength != 1) {
              if (!cell.Value.Equals(o)) {
                return true; // this fails on a Char.value 'C' != "C"
              }
            } else {
              string str = o.ToString();
              if (!cell.Value.Equals(str[0])) {
                return true;
              }
            }
            found = true;
          }
          if (found) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Feel free to critique anything in my code. I hate hearing I don't do something the best way, but it always spurs growth in my abilities.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you might be running into a unicode issue. nchar is not the same as a char data type. If both are cast into strings and compared, they may not match. I don't know on that but just something you might want to check

Comment: When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL doesn't have a `char` data type. All it has are strings — `char(n)`, `varchar(n)`, `nchar(n)` and `nvarchar(n)`. You'll notice that `char` is conspicuous by its absence in the conversion chart at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

If you are using a SqlDataReader, you can retrieve your char value as an array of chars via the SQLDataReader's [`GetChars()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchars.aspx) method:

```
SqlDataReader sdr = ...
...
int    ordinalColumnNumber = 3 ;
char[] buffer              = new char[1] ;
int    charCount           = sdr.GetChars( ordinalColumnNumber , 0 , buffer , 0 , buffer.Length ) ;
if ( charCount != buffer.Length ) throw new InvalidOperationException() ;
char value = buffer[0] ;
```

That's probably as close as your going to get. The alternative would be to store your single char as a `smallint`. The C# language specification defines an implicit conversion from `char` to `short` or `ushort`, so a comparison should work as you expect:

```
public bool Test( char value , short expected )
{
  return ( value == expected ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is common. No database I know of has a single-char type, just strings of length 1.

It should not be such a problem to either convert you char to a string, or compare it to fieldValue[0].

An alternative is storing your types as SmallInt values (possibly mapped to enums).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around the NCHAR to String conversion.

Can you add a property to the model that converts it, e.g.

```
public char CharStatus { get { return status[0]; } }
```

Make sense?!

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a helper method based on the code Nicholas provided above as well. You simply pass the current data reader object as a parameter followed by the column you intend to query.

```
char isOkToEmailPromos = GetAChar(reader, 9); // Calling method


private char GetAChar(SqlDataReader rd, int column)
    {
        char[] value = new char[1];
        long charCount = (long)rd.GetChars(column, 0, value, 0, value.Length); 
        if (charCount != value.Length) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return value[0];

    }
```

Comment: That was pretty much what I did, but that project is long gone now. :)